# Using Swift to retrieve information from MySQL database

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

Is there a better way to retrieve information from a MySQL database without using PHP. I have been trying to use PHP for several days but have had no luck.

Comment: You can technically retrieve information from a MySQL database in nearly any modern language (Node, Ruby, Python, Java, PHP, etc.) However, if you are specifically trying to pull the information into an iOS app, then, as pointed out, your best bet is to either use the API provided by the owner of the database or (if you are the owner) build your own API in one of the aforementioned languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an api that sends json formatted data. Then it is really easy to deal with that using Swift.